# Why i am see server error 500 in my website when Debug = False in django

Tags: python, django, django-views

I am see Server Error 500 in my website [www.softdlr.com] after i make Debug = Flase in **settings.py**

- this problem appear when i do search in other language ( except English )
- when i use contact form

how to fix this error (My priorities is to fix the contact form that i using gmail )

forms.py

```
# contact form
class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    contact_name = forms.CharField(required=True,label='Your name ')
    contact_email = forms.EmailField(required=True,label='Your email ')
    title = forms.CharField(required=True,label='The Subject')
    content = forms.CharField(required=True,label='Full Deatils 
    ',max_length=500,widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={"rows":5, "cols":30}) )
```

views.py

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from first_app import forms
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import ContactForm
from django.core.mail import EmailMessage

# Contact form view

def contact(request):
    Contact_Form = ContactForm
    if request.method == 'POST':
    form = Contact_Form(data=request.POST)

    if form.is_valid():
        contact_name = request.POST.get('contact_name')
        contact_email = request.POST.get('contact_email')
        contact_content = request.POST.get('content')
        title = request.POST.get('title')

        template = loader.get_template('html_file/contact_form.txt')
        context = {
            'contact_name' : contact_name,
            'contact_email' : contact_email,
            'title' : title,
            'contact_content' : contact_content,

        }

        content = template.render(context)

        email = EmailMessage(
            "New contact form email",
            content,
            "Creative web" + '',
            ['myemail@gmail.com'],
            headers = { 'Reply To': contact_email }
        )

        email.send()


        return redirect('Success')
return render(request, 'html_file/contact_us.html', {'form':Contact_Form })
```

settings.py

```
# email message contact
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST= 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER= 'myemail@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD= 'mypass'
EMAIL_USE_TLS= True
EMAIL_PORT= 587
```

Comment: Do you not have access to any logging? A 500 error could be caused by almost anything - most likely an exception in your Python code, but only logging will tell you what it is once you have (correctly, in production) turned DEBUG mode off.

Comment: If you don't have access to logging, try putting `try` `except` blocks around different parts of your code and return a simple error number in a http response. Also your code after `if request.method == 'POST':` should be indented.

Comment: for contact i tried make debug = True to see what is the problem and this is problem :


SMTPAuthenticationError at /Contact_US
(534, b'5.7.14 <https://accounts.google.com/signin/continue?sarp=1&scc=1&plt=AKgnsbt\n5.7.14 nGT21ybKJb-qYJrjOPRtCzuQjls8XfKxOK_TQc63LPzB_DyFQva-bfIaq4hprwHYq1Z7q\n5.7.14 1ovmO_aGsC6MWE_AAvmA8sLGC4bV3zf-MS9qtQjo37n99FF1u3ZlU2k3dA2sm8DH>\n5.7.14 Please log in via your web browser and then try again.\n5.7.14  Learn more at\n5.7.14  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754 r2sm283860wmg.2 - gsmtp')

Comment: i will try this in search thank you 
now i will fix contact first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for contact form i fix the problem by doing this :

Going to https://accounts.google.com/DisplayUnlockCaptcha
and then retrying the operation, worked a treat